# Firebase currentUser.getIdToken() returns custom token after signInWithCustomToken

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm debugging session timeout issues on a Next.js WEB/Node app that uses Firebase Auth for sign in. I am leveraging custom tokens for granular firestore security rules. While debugging, I'm finding that the idToken I send to the backend to create the custom token appears to be a custom token itself after the initial client call. At the very least it contains my custom claims and so far as I understand from the docs, the server can only deal with idTokens as per the glaring red notice at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens . I don't know if this is the source of the timeout errors, but it seems peculiar.

**Update**

While investigating why the `picture` field was not present on the decoded tokens, I discovered that the first argument to `createCustomToken` was incorrectly the firestore doc id of the user collection doc rather than the id token's `uid` field. All the same clarifying questions apply still. However, I'm hoping this misstep addresses things. It made the `picture` field return on the subsequent decodings of the token. However, the token still has my custom claims which may or may not be an issue still.

**Initial Login**

Web Client code

```
signInResult = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
//... exception handling ...
const { user } = signInResult;
const fbToken = await user.getIdToken();
// axios POST request to backend with fbToken in data payload
```

Backend Code using FB Admin client

```
decodedToken = await adminClient.auth().verifyIdToken(data.fbIdToken);
//... validation and exception handling ...
// . If I log out decodedToken:
{ name: 'Blaine Garrett',
  picture: '...',
  iss: '...',
  aud: '...',
  auth_time: 1569160850,
  user_id: '...',
  sub: '...',
  iat: 1569160850,
  exp: 1569164450,
  email: '...',
  email_verified: true,
  firebase:
   { identities: { 'google.com': [Array], email: [Array] },
     sign_in_provider: 'google.com' },
  uid: '...' }
{ issued: 2019-09-22T14:00:50.000Z,
  expires: 2019-09-22T15:00:50.000Z }


let userId = decodedToken.uid; // As per update, this was not the case originally

// Build custom claims
customToken = await adminClient.auth().createCustomToken(userId, additionalClaims);
// return customToken in a 200 response
```

On the client in the response from server

```
...
await firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken);
...
```

**Subsequent Calls**
If I then call `const firebaseIdToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();` after the above `signInWithCustomToken` and send that result to the backend and log the token, the decoded token is:

```
{ email: '...',
  user_roles: [ 'admin', 'support' ], // <-- my custom claims
  iss: '...',
  aud: '...',
  auth_time: 1569161153,
  user_id: '...',
  sub: '...',
  iat: 1569161163,
  exp: 1569164763,
  firebase: { identities: {}, sign_in_provider: 'custom' },
  uid: '...' }
{ issued: 2019-09-22T14:06:03.000Z,
  expires: 2019-09-22T15:06:03.000Z }
// Note: not everything is present on this token, including `picture` property and `email_verified`, etc
```

So even though I call `currentUser.getIdToken()` on the client, it appears to be my custom token - or at least have my custom claims and some of the original id token fields missing.

1. Is that expected behavior? i.e. getIdToken will return the custom token if signInWithCustomToken was previously called.
2. Is it valid to attempt to use verifyIdToken on the server if the given token is a custom token?
3. Is that actually a customToken or does FB just preserve the claims. (the missing profile field confuses me).
4. Is there a way to differentiate a custom token from an idToken?
5. *Per update above* What's the purpose of being able to send any arbitrary value for the first argument of createCustomToken? eg. I passed `asdf` and the token was minted fine and subsequently decoded fine. Would this have an effect of session timeout?

Thanks for any insight. Again, I don't know if this is the source of my timeout issues, but I ran across this trying to debug and it made me question my understanding of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

When you add custom claims to a Firebase Authentication user account, they are not immediately "visible" to the client until their ID token refreshes somehow.  This behavior is [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client):

> After new claims are modified on a user via the Admin SDK, they are
>   propagated to an authenticated user on the client side via the ID
>   token in the following ways:
>
> - A user signs in or re-authenticates after the custom claims are modified. The ID token issued as a result will contain the latest
>     claims.
> - An existing user session gets its ID token refreshed after an older token expires.
> - An ID token is force refreshed by calling currentUser.getIdToken(true).

So, if you need the client to immediately start using new claims, you should force a refresh using the third bullet point.  Pass `true` to getIdToken.

Comment: To clarify, are you suggesting that I should call `currentUser.getIdToken(true)` immediately after `signInWithCustomToken(customToken) ` after getting the customToken from the backend? Wouldn't that be covered by the first bullet point?

Comment: If you want to make the user sign out and sign back in, that's your choice.  But it's not the same thing, and possibly inconvenient for the user.

Comment: I do not want to inconvenience the user in that way, no. That said, it sounds like I should call `signInWithCustomToken()` followed by `currentUser.getIdToken(true)`.  Would I need to do anything with the result or does simply calling getIdToken do the trick?

Comment: According to the documentation, that's all you have to do.

Comment: This is probably a silly question at this point, but do I need to make a custom token to have custom claims? I'm starting to think they're completely separate concepts.

Comment: No, not required.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the answer is to not use custom tokens merely to add custom claims for your firebase rules. They are completely different concepts.

Custom tokens are to implement an unsupported auth provider in addition to those Fb supports - i.e. Google, Microsoft, etc. Custom claims are key/val pairs you can leverage in your security rules and via the claims property on the user.getIdTokenResult() object in the client.

The timeout issue I was debugging was due to trying to re-use the custom token, which doesn't need to be refreshed because it's not what is is for. getIdToken() returns the Id token encoded with any claims that were on the original custom token when it was minted.